# flashdata codeigniter with array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have problem with array on flashdata codeigniter to send alert, if without framework this code work correcly, I modified this to codeigniter, but it does not work.

Controller Code:

```
    function reply(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $err = array();

    if(!$_POST['msg']) {
        $err[] = 'all the fields must be filled in!';
    }

    else if(!count($err)){
        $data = array(
            'DestinationNumber'=> $this->input->post('hp'),
            'TextDecoded'=> $this->input->post('msg'),
            'i_id'=> $this->input->post('id'));

        $this->inbox_model->reply($data);

        if($data >= 1) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata['msg']['success']='Send Success!';
        }

        else {
            $err[] = 'Send Failed!';
        }

    }

    if(count($err)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata['msg']['err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }

    redirect('sms/inbox/read/'.$id);
}
```

View Code :

```
if($this->session->flashdata['msg']['err']){
     echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>
           <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
           ".$this->session->flashdata['msg']['err']."</div>";
           $this->session->unset_flashdata['msg']['err'];
}                    
if($this->session->flashdata['msg']['success']){
     echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
           <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
           ".$this->session->flashdata['msg']['success']."</div>";
           $this->session->unset_flashdata['msg']['success'];
}
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What kind of error or output do you get? Please try to provide as much information as you can to be able to get better answers.

Comment: i have no error, another code works fine, only flashdata not shown

Comment: Did you check your webserver logs?

Comment: there nothing error on web server, i change config log CI to 1, and found this on log folder CI,   ERROR - 2016-10-09 00:15:03 --> 404 Page Not Found: ../modules/sms/controllers//index
ERROR - 2016-10-09 00:15:05 --> Severity: Notice --> Indirect modification of overloaded property CI_Session::$set_flashdata has no effect C:\xampp\htdocs\myaps\application\modules\sms\controllers\inbox.php 66
ERROR - 2016-10-09 00:15:05 --> 404 Page Not Found: ../modules/sms/controllers//index.   and inbox.php 66 code  is $this->session->set_flashdata['msg']['err'] = implode('<br />',$err);

Comment: Go to the codeigniter website and read the user guide relating to flashdata Or read the destructions in your local copy of the user_guide... When something dont work, go back and read up on it... To give you a hint, you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: Ya, i was read again, i think imposible using array on flashdata, i have to make value one by one, i just think maybe someone have problem like me, because this is posible if without framework, i just think maybe CI using this with diferent way, i just dont know, thats why i ask.. But thanks all for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller :

```
$err = array();
if(!$_POST['msg']) {
$err['msg_err'] = '<strong>Oh snap!</strong> all the fields must be filled in';}
```

View :

```
if($this->session->flashdata('err')){
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
".$this->session->flashdata('err')['msg_err']."</div>"; }
```

Answer (score 8):

you could set array to flashdata session using the simple way

```
$array_msg = array('first'=>'<p>msg 1</p>','second'=>'<p>msg2</p>');
```

then pass it to session

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg',$array_msg);
```

then access it

```
$msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg');
echo $msg['first'];
```

Comment: haii, thanks for giving a hint, with a little modification the code works now, event not as perfect as i want, this is the code :